# write a css3 rule to match 2 nth child elements by N

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Given the following html block

```
<div><span></span><span></span><span></span>
    <div><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
</div>​
```

and this css for it

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70px;
    height: 50px;
}
div > div > span { visibility: hidden; }
span:not(:first-child) { margin-left: 5px; }
span:first-child {background-color: red;}
span:nth-child(2) {background-color: green;}
span:nth-child(3) {background-color: blue;}

span:nth-child(1):hover ~ div span:nth-child(1),
span:nth-child(2):hover ~ div span:nth-child(2),
span:nth-child(3):hover ~ div span:nth-child(3)
{ visibility: visible; }
​
```

Can you rewrite the last rule using some smart css so that it always makes visible the nth-child from the inner div for the N you are currently hovering in the outer one, no matter how many div's there are?

Demo in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/E34ay/3/

In other words I would like something like:

```
span:nth-child(N):hover ~ div span:nth-child(N) { visibility: visible; }
```

but which will match only the already matched N not all the children (first N = second N)

This is for a gallery that will act like this http://jsfiddle.net/2zFsf/

Comment: It isn't possible to write a simplified rule for this but if you altered the html you could use the `+` selector, then hide/show every other one.

Comment: Yeah, but I want this for a gallery, the final html is a bit more complex and it would force me to put a inside a which is illegal, I'll put an updated the fiddle so you can see what I mean

Comment: @mdk Added link to fiddle demonstrating what I want, it's because of the big link on the inner div that I can't use your suggestion, if you can come up with something to work around that and have an extensible N I'll accept the answer. But all links must stay where they are on the page and clicking on the big div must always go to #a and there must be a single link to #a.

Comment: I've had a good look, I just can't see any way to do this, I'll get back to you though if anything comes up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a case like this where CSS alone isn't powerful enough for what you want to do, SASS (or SCSS) can really help you out.

Using the [`@for` control directive](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#id11), it's as simple as changing one number to scale up:

```
@for $i from 1 through 3 {
  span:nth-child(#{$i}):hover ~ div span:nth-child(#{$i}) { 
      visibility: visible; 
  }
}
```

Which compiles to your exact CSS. Change the 3 to however many spans you plan on having.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IGegw)

Comment: A good idea I'll keep it in mind, hope there will still be a solution for an infinite N, you get a vote for now...